# Android Firebase retrieve data back to gridView

Tags: java, android

I'm new to programming and I just started doing my first android project. I've been stuck in the problem for hours and still have no idea why it doesn't work. Here's the data structure below.

[image]

I want to add journals for their respective users, the addJournal() function that I implemented is working. But it crashes when I retrieve back those journals from the database to the gridView.

Here's how I add Journals to the database below:

```
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        journalReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        String journalName = etJournalName.getText().toString().trim();
        String companyName = etCompanyName.getText().toString().trim();
        String journalColor = "blankForNow";
        String userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
        String journalID = journalReference.push().getKey();

        //validation
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(journalName)){
            etJournalName.setError("Journal name must not be empty");
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(companyName)){
            etCompanyName.setError("Company name must not be empty");
        } else {
            //storing data to the database...
            Journal journal = new Journal(journalID, userID, journalName, companyName, journalColor);
            journalReference.child("users")
                    .child(userID)
                    .child("journals")
                    .child(journalID).setValue(journal);
        }
```

And here's how I retrieve data below:

```
    DatabaseReference journalRef = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    journalRef.child("users")
    .child(userID)
    .child("journals").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            journalArrayList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot journalDS : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Journal journal = journalDS.getValue(Journal.class);
                journalArrayList.add(journal);
            }
            gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, journalArrayList);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, Strin
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post error log here?

Comment: Please post your error log. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just figure out where i can find the logs...

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.ArrayList.clear()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.cabbage.sdpjournal.MainActivity$1.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:75)

Comment: @Jamen check my answer edit 1

Comment: @akhilesh0707 thanks, but there is another exception oh my gosh... DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.cabbage.sdpjournal.Model.Journal... do you have any idea that can help me? thanks again.

Comment: post your Journal class

Comment: @akhilesh0707 posted on the bottom

Comment: also, print log on Log.d("Journal "," ==>"+journalDS.toString()); inside your for loop

Comment: @akhilesh0707 posted on the bottom as well

Comment: @Jamen i made changes in my answer check edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` insted of `addChildEventListener`

Hope this might help you

```
DatabaseReference journalRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
journalRef.child("users").child(userID).child("journals").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        journalArrayList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot journalDS : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Journal journal = journalDS.getValue(Journal.class);
            journalArrayList.add(journal);
        }
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, journalArrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

`ValueEventListener` get all the data in a single bunch, where as `ChildEventListener` get the data one by one record for the perticular node.
I recommend that you try it. Create a snippet for each `ValueEventListener` and `ChildEventListener` check the behaviour

**Edit 1**

You are getting NullPointerException just because you do not initialize your `journalArrayList` list

initialize your List

```
journalArrayList=new ArrayList<>()
```

**Edit 2** you can get value using map try below solution

```
for (DataSnapshot journalDS : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) journalDS.getValue();
    String journalName = map.get("journalName");
    String companyName = map.get("companyName");
    String journalColor = map.get("journalColor");
    String userID = map.get("userID");
    String journalID = map.get("journalID");
    Journal journal = new Journal(journalID, userID, journalName, companyName, journalColor);
    journalArrayList.add(journal);
}
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.cabbage.sdpjournal, PID: 5840
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.ArrayList.clear()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.cabbage.sdpjournal.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:75)

Comment: @Jamen you are getting nullpointer error just because of you are not initiliaze your  journalArrayList.clear();

Comment: @akhilesh0707 I solved it by like you said change the addChildEvent to addValueEvent... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code,using Get and set methods.

```
public class Journal {
    private String journalID;
    private String userID;
    private String journalName;
    private String companyName;
    private String journalColor;

    public Journal() {
    }

    public Journal(String journalID, String userID, String journalName, String companyName, String journalColor) {
        this.journalID = journalID;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.journalName = journalName;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.journalColor = journalColor;
    }

    public String getJournalID() {
        return journalID;
    }

    public void setJournalID(String journalID) {
        this.journalID = journalID;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getJournalName() {
        return journalName;
    }

    public void setJournalName(String journalName) {
        this.journalName = journalName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getJournalColor() {
        return journalColor;
    }

    public void setJournalColor(String journalColor) {
        this.journalColor = journalColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

D/Journal:  ==>DataSnapshot { key = -KsvqM79AsS1bPUgtngB, value = {userID=qAzq0h3E8oaUn09SkG0hWhFfTDT2, journalName=Journals001, journalID=-KsvqM79AsS1bPUgtngB, companyName=com001, journalColor=blankForNow} }
09-01 21:20:20.364 30374-30374/com.cabbage.sdpjournal 
D/Journal:  ==>DataSnapshot { key = -KsvzWaNFsYX488MLSIK, value = {userID=qAzq0h3E8oaUn09SkG0hWhFfTDT2, journalName=Journal007, journalID=-KsvzWaNFsYX488MLSIK, companyName=com007, journalColor=blankForNow} }
09-01 21:20:20.364 30374-30374/com.cabbage.sdpjournal 
D/Journal:  ==>DataSnapshot { key = -KsvzdIrgwFG3DaLXyt1, value = {userID=qAzq0h3E8oaUn09SkG0hWhFfTDT2, journalName=Journal008, journalID=-KsvzdIrgwFG3DaLXyt1, companyName=com008, journalColor=blankForNow} }
09-01 21:20:20.365 30374-30374/com.cabbage.sdpjournal D/Journal:  ==>DataSnapshot { key = -KswCFyIifHf--smTXxu, value = {userID=qAzq0h3E8oaUn09SkG0hWhFfTDT2, journalName=Journals008, journalID=-KswCFyIifHf--smTXxu, companyName=com008, journalColor=blankForNow} }
09-01 21:20:20.365 30374-30374/com.cabbage.sdpjournal D/Journal:  ==>DataSnapshot { key = -KswV-O82jgtGOaRr6BK, value = {userID=qAzq0h3E8oaUn09SkG0hWhFfTDT2, journalName=journal009, journalID=-KswV-O82jgtGOaRr6BK, companyName=com009, journalColor=blankForNow} }